# Unable to save Email property to sql in due to SQL Exception Error :"Null insert not allowed" except property is not null??(ORM-code first)

Tags: ef-code-first, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to generate the email when an employee is created using properties (FirstName and LastName) from the base class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

}

 public class Employee : Person
{
    public Employee()
    {
        Packages = new List<Package>();

    }
    public string Email { get =>$"{FirstName[0]}.{LastName}@GTravel.com.au"; }

    public IEnumerable<Package> Packages { get; set; }
}
```

So the output should be something like: J.Smith@GTravel.com.au
I then want to be able to save this employee into a sql database with Person as the Entity/Table and Employee as the discriminator.

```
using (var gtmsdb = new GTMSDbContext())
        {

            var newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                DOB = new DateTime(1992, 09, 16),
                Phone = "03-1234-567"

            };
            gtmsdb.People.Add(newEmployee);
            gtmsdb.SaveChanges();

        }
```

[Shows Employee in debugger with email created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMMQL.png)

When I run the code it creates the employee with the Email in the correct format and everything but when I try saving to the database it returns the error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Email', table
>   'GTMSDatabase.dbo.People'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I also tried saving the Email as a simple {get; set;} and then hard coded the email:

```
 public string Email { get; set; }


 var newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                DOB = new DateTime(1992, 09, 16),
                Phone = "032166702",
                Email ="j.smith@gtravel"

            };
            gtmsdb.People.Add(newEmployee);
            gtmsdb.SaveChanges();
```

But that still returned the same error message.
 I also tested with other(new) properties that worked perfectly fine, deleted and retried the migrations, checked in my database for an error there but I am now unsure of the next step to take. There are no references to Email in my Context so is it something that I need to be initialising there?

Edit: I created another smaller scale project where I ran the exact same code and the email saved with no issues:

```
using (var db = new ETDbContext())
        {
            var newEmployee = new Employee
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                DOB = new DateTime(1992, 09, 16),
                Phone = "032166702"

            };
            db.People.Add(newEmployee);
            var nc = new Customer
            {
                FirstName = "Jane",
                LastName = "Doe",
                DOB = new DateTime(1992, 09, 16),
                Phone = "032166702",
                Email = "customerEmail"
            };
            db.People.Add(nc);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

I tried to add a Customer just to make sure everything worked but ran into the same problem! Anytime I would create an employee it would save no issues but with the customer it returned the same null reference error

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked before it tries to save if the Email has been set?, If it goes null then the set isn't working, I will do something like below.

```
 var newEmployee = new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "John",
            LastName = "Smith",
            DOB = new DateTime(1992, 09, 16),
            Phone = "03-1234-567",
            Email = '';
        };
 newEmployee.Email = newEmployee.FirstName.Substring(0,1).ToLower() + 
 newEmployee.LastName.ToLower() +"@gtravel";
```

Comment: There's a link in the question with the screenshot that shows the employee being created with the correct email and everything. It wouldn't let me post a direct pic but it pretty much just shows everything being created correctly but it's the save that I couldn't get

Comment: I didn't see the picture. Can you show me your modelCreating context? Could it be because you are sending 6 properties and you db is expecting 5.